# PrimeNG Table Does Not Order Data Well

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a PrimeNG Table in my Angular 10 project and the problem is that the data and headers are not ordered well. I Add a scroll to see if it solved the problem and it did not work, in a previous project I had a similar amount of data and I used DataTables from npm's angular-datatables package and I had no problem.

Image:

[image]

Code HTML:

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center mt-5 mr-5">
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center"> 
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="cardForm">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Ingresar Equipo</h2>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 ml-5">
        <input pInputText type="text" placeholder="Buscar por Nombre de Equipo" class="p-column-filter mr-5" (input)="datatable.filter($event.target.value, 'nombre', 'startsWith')">
        <div class="p-mb-3">
            <p-button type="button" icon="pi pi-chevron-left" (click)="prev()" [disabled]="isFirstPage()" styleClass="p-button-text"></p-button>
            <p-button type="button" icon="pi pi-refresh" (click)="reset()" styleClass="p-button-text"></p-button>
            <p-button type="button" icon="pi pi-chevron-right" (click)="next()" [disabled]="isLastPage()" styleClass="p-button-text"></p-button>
        </div>
            <p-table #datatable [value] = "equipos" [paginator] = "true" [rows] = "rows" [showCurrentPageReport]="true" [(first)]="first"
                currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="100%" scrollWidth="100%">
                <ng-template pTemplate = "header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Rotutlo</th>
                        <th>Nombre Equipo</th>
                        <th>Serie</th>
                        <th>Fecha AD</th>
                        <th>Fecha EPO</th>
                        <th>Fecha Inventario</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>Direccion IP</th>
                        <th>SubNet</th>
                        <th>Direccion MAC</th>
                        <th>Chasis</th>
                        <th>Dominio</th>
                        <th>Sistema Operativo</th>
                        <th>Arquitectura SO</th>
                        <th>Fabricante</th>
                        <th>Modelo</th>
                        <th>Obsolencia</th>
                        <th>Procesador</th>
                        <th>Velocidad Procesador</th>
                        <th>Capacidad Disco Duro</th>
                        <th>Capacidad Disponible Disco Duro</th>
                        <th>Porcentaje Disponible Disco Duro</th>
                        <th>Memoria RAM</th>
                        <th>Modificar/Eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate = "body" let-equipo>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{equipo.idEquipo}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.rotulo}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.nombre}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.fechaad}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.fechaepo}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.fechainventario}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.estado}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.direccionip}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.subnet}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.direccionmac}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.chasis}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.dominio}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.sistemaoperativo}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.arquitecturaso}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.fabricante}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.modelo}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.obsolencia}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.procesador}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.velocidadprocesador}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.capacidaddiscoduro}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.capacidaddiscodurodisponible}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.porcentajedisponiblediscoduro}}</td>
                        <td>{{equipo.memoriaram}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
                                <i class="material-icons">open_in_new</i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EquipoService } from '../../services/equipo.service'
import { Equipo }from '../../models/equipo'
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-equipo',
  templateUrl: './equipo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./equipo.component.scss']
})
export class EquipoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private equipoService : EquipoService,
    private fromBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ) { }

    equipos : Equipo[];

    first = 0;

    rows = 6;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEquipments();
  }


  next() {
    this.first = this.first + this.rows;
  }

  prev() {
    this.first = this.first - this.rows;
  }

  reset() {
    this.first = 0;
  }

  isLastPage(): boolean {
    return this.equipos ? this.first === (this.equipos.length - this.rows): true;
  }

  isFirstPage(): boolean {
    return this.equipos ? this.first === 0 : true;
}

  getEquipments(){
    this.equipoService.getEquipments().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.equipos = res
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

I have not applied any css to the template.

How can I solve this?

Beforehand thank you very much.

**EDIT**

StackBlitz Link. I did not add data to the table, but you can see the problem.
[StackBlitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqntks?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: can you create a stackblitz ?

Comment: Ok give me a minute

Comment: I updated the post @AbhinavKumar

Comment: Add some mock data

Comment: From  PrimeNG docs:
For performance reasons, default table-layout is fixed meaning the cell widths do not depend on their content. If you require cells to scale based on their contents set autoLayout property to true. Note that Scrollable and/or Resizable tables do not support auto layout due to technical reasons.